# Update Recyclerview item after receiving a broadcast

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items displayed using recyclerview. I want to update the contents on the list with the data I receive from my broadcast receiver. I have been scratching my head for the past 24 hours trying to figure out if I should just recreate the entire list with the updated data or if I should remove the item that is supposed to be updated and add it again with new data. Does anyone have any advice or tips on how I should approach this  better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call notifyDataSetChanged method of your adapter. [Explanation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: I actually used this approach at first but I didn't see any results, so I just revisited it like you suggested and I noticed I had a logic error in my code before that is why I wasn't seeing any results. Everything working perfectly now, Thank you